# 2.8 What happened with the Edge Loops?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edges

The Edge Loops selection function used to be in the Edge menu (ctrl + E) but now it's gone, and I guess can only be accessed from the bottom (now top) bar > Select > Select Loops > Edge loops.

This is pretty frustrating for me to have to go through 3 different dropdowns to the use the same function I used to access through just pressing CTRL+E, is there any way to change this or at least any reason for it being moved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal loop-select shortcut in Blender is to click one edge of the loop while holding down <kbd>alt</kbd>. This works in both 2.7x and 2.8x. <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd> clicking an edge will select an edge ring. Make sure you are in edge select mode and not face or vertex select. In face select mode, these will select loops/rings of faces. In vertex select mode, it will try and select a loop/ring, but since edges often share a vertex this will probably select more than you intended.